# wso2 carbon studio - registry extension file editor

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I would like to create custom artifact in WSO2 Governance Registry.
Is there an editor to create Governance Registry extension file in WSO2 carbon studio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Please refer to [[1]](http://wso2.org/project/developer-studio/2.0.1/docs/registry_category.html#RegistryFilter) for available registry tools in DeveloperStudio.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: those tools are to implement filter and aspect java implementation. I expected an XML editor enriched to create extension file.